# having issue with background-image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I want integreat this JavaScript code to change the background-image depending on current time .
the problem is nothing show up if i put the code in a simple html file.

The code is woking live here though: http://jsbin.com/femem/1/edit

here is the code:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>

        <script src="js/bg.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>
        some text
    </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code JavaScript:

```
     var d = new Date(),
        h = d.getHours(),
        i;

    if (h < 6) {
        i = "http://placehold.it/450x150";
    } else if (h < 10) {
        i = "http://placehold.it/250x150";
    } else if (h < 18) {
        i = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
    } else if (h < 23) {
        i = "bgbody.jpg";
    } else {
        i = "http://placehold.it/450x150";
    }

    document.body.style.background = "url(" + i + ")";
```

Comment: If it's working on jsbin, there's not much we can help with, there's not a lot that could go wrong with that code?

Comment: if I run the code locally, it don't work, it work only on JSbin

Comment: Then open the browser console and check for errors, something is obviously wrong.

Comment: here is the errorI get on the browser consol  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point when the script is run, the `<body>` has not been reached yet and therefore `document.body` is undefined (as the error you get in the console should tell you).

To fix this, simply move your script inside the `<body>` - it can be right at the top if you want.

Alternatively, with basic PHP:

```
<body style="background-image:url(<?php
    $h = date("H");
    if( $h < 6) echo "http://placehold.it/450x150";
    elseif( $h < 10) echo "http://placehold.it/250x150";
    elseif( $h < 18) echo "http://placehold.it/350x150";
    elseif( $h < 23) echo "bgbody.jpg";
    else echo "http://placehold.it/450x150";
?>)">
```

This would avoid a "Flash of Unstyled Content" (FOUC)

Comment: But where can I put this PHP code if am using WordPress?

Comment: The PHP code relies on you being able to use PHP. If you can't, then you can't use it and will have to rely on the JavaScript instead.

Comment: oh, I got it... I didn't see that it was on the open body tag. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I have a question, if I want add a `background-attachment:fixed;` propriety, how can I add it? i've try to add it in my CSS but it is not applied.

Comment: Use `backgroundImage`, not `background`, when changing the image.

Comment: yeah but where I should put it? by the way, I didn't you the PHP version... I used the JavaScript Version and place the code after the body as you suggested.

Comment: `.style.backgroundImage` to replace `.style.background` in your code.

Comment: but I don't want to change the omage actually, it work like I wanted... I just want to add propriety like `background-repeat:no-repeat` ... you understand?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but using `.style.background` NUKES any other `background-*` properties you have on there.